# phpseclib SFTP can`t put file with special characters

Tags: php, laravel-4, phpseclib, php-5.6, net-sftp

Following code is used to upload file to SFTP:

```
\SSH::into('server')->put($localFile, $remotePath);
```

It uses [phpseclib/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/master/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php) behind the scenes.
Upload does not work when trying to upload file with special characters in it e.g. `"file_ü_e.jpg"`

Uploading such file via GUI tool to given server works so the question - is it possible and what should be done to upload it via script?

Answer (score -1):

idk if Laravel creates a wrapper around phpseclib's put but, with phpseclib, your `put($localFile, $remotePath)` call would be wrong. With phpseclib if you want to upload a file on the local filesystem to a remote SFTP server you'd need to do something like this:

```
->put($remotePath, $localFile, NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE);
```

Comment: It does exactly that - https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Remote/SecLibGateway.php#L142